# SharePoint Online search text inside documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

Can SharePoint online be configured to search inside the actual files of a document library? For examples, word documents, excel files, PDF files (with searchable text), and html files.

I've come across many articles that explain how this can be achieved using on-prem SharePoint, but have yet to come across any regarding SharePoint online.

In this [Overview of search](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/overview-of-search) documentation it only mentions that sites columns and values are added to the search index. It doesn't mention whether the actual content inside the documents are searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Just like on-prem Search, this is automatically done with the same limitations about how much of the document it indexes (64Kb, if I recall correctly, but I could be off a bit). There is no way to either turn this on or off -- it is always enabled.

Comment: As far as my testing has gone, the search doesn't search inside the actual document contents though.

Comment: Search indexes the content of the file. This would be an issue with your testing.

Comment: Is there any documentation on which file types are supported? I'm wondering in particular whether it can index the content of PDFs (with selectable text) and also html files.